# How to remove special characters from money column (only have dollars) No Date and country

Tags: sql

I want to only have the money each film gains not the country and the date. right now each one of them has something like `$999,046 (USA) (14 August 2011) $xxxx` country data. How can I only get `$999,046, $xxx`. They have different dates and some of them have (Non-USA).

I just want to have the money value not the date and country

Comment: Is your column a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: I put backticks around your example data and desired results so that it's more clear what the data is in this question. Please correct if `"country data"` should be included as part of the actual data. It was not clear to me.

Comment: More importantly, what RDBMS are you using (sql server, mysql, postgres, oracle, etc)?

Comment: Lastly, can you provide more sample data so that we can have an idea of the pattern from which we need to extract your two data points.

Comment: Right now my column has both numbers (like $999,046) and other characters(like (USA) (14 August 2011)). I only want to have$999,046 in my column. Other sample data: $998,963 (USA) (13 December 2015), $998,697 (USA) (22 April 2012), $994,653 (Non-USA), $994,245 (USA) (8 July 2012). I am using mysql.

Comment: Also when I want to order by the money money like $999,046 (USA) (14 August 2011). Some greater numbers like $11,000,000 (worldwide) are not ordered as greater than $999,046 (USA) (14 August 2011).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what RDBMS you are using, but if using SQL Server, you could always do something like this.

```
SELECT (LEFT(money_column, CHARINDEX(' ', money_column)-1) + ', ' 
  + RIGHT(money_column, CHARINDEX(' ', money_column)-1)) as money_values
FROM film_table
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/57294/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it seems grabbing the text to the left of the first space will do the trick.  If so, do this:

```
select case charindex(' ', moneycolumn) 
when 0 then moneycolumn
else substring(moneycolumn, 1, charindex(' ', moneycolumn)) end dollars 
from filmtable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUBSTRING() as below-

```
DECLARE @T VARCHAR(200)
SET @T = '$999,046 (USA) (14 August 2011) $xxxx'

SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(@T,0,CHARINDEX(' ',@T,0)) 
    +', '+
    SUBSTRING(@T,CHARINDEX('$',@T,CHARINDEX(' ',@T,0)),LEN(@T))
```